# Error Promise.all

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop, callback

I'm trying to use Promise.all function but actually as I start nodeJS and I discover asynchronous technology I don't know where is my problem in my code...
Basically I would like to use Promise.all to make my own callback in a function then In my loop For I create several Promise and if I can save my data then I'll resolve my current Promise. 
But apparently my promise.all is executed immediately and it don't wait for my others Promise..
See below ..

```
function persistMAP(jsonData,callback){
//Deck persistance
const promises  =[];
for(var i=0; i<1; i++){
    (function(i) {
        var rowData = new DeckDatabase({ 
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            DeckNumber: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].DeckNumber),
            x: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].x),
            y: Number(jsonData.Deck[i].y),
        });
        rowData.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);

            for(var index=0; j=jsonData.Units.length,index<j; index++){
                (function(index) {
                    promises.push(
                        new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                            var unit = new MapDatabase({ 
                                UnitID:jsonData.Units[index].UnitID,
                                TypeID: Number(jsonData.Units[index].TypeID),
                                x: Number(jsonData.Units[index].x),
                                y: Number(jsonData.Units[index].y),
                                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(((jsonData.Units[index].Code).toLowerCase()) + 'dd40c86762e0fb12000003'), // mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jsonData.Units[i].Code + 'dd40c86762e0fb12000003')
                                MainClass: jsonData.Units[index].MainClass,
                                Orientation: jsonData.Units[index].Orientation,
                                Postion: jsonData.Units[index].Postion,
                                Deck : String(rowData._id)
                            });

                            unit.save(function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    reject();
                                    throw err
                                }
                                else{
                                    console.log('save');
                                    resolve(); 
                                }

                            });

                        }) 
                    );

                })(index);
            }   

          });

    })(i);
} 
Promise.all(promises)
.then(()=>{
    console.log('start find');
    callback(); 
})  
};
```

and here is where I call my function

```
else{
 var jobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
 console.log("persist begin");
 persistMAP(jobj,function(){
       console.log('retrieve Done');
       MapDatabase.find()
        .populate('Deck')
        .exec(function(err, finalData){
            console.log('send');
            res.send(finalData);
        })
 }); 
}
```

So why It doesn't wait ? :(

Comment: It works with a timeout but there is another way ? because I find that this use of timeout is really not a proper way because basically the time which is set is random I mean it isn't optimized

Answer (score 0):

You do an async operation in your for:

```
for(var i=0; i<1; i++){
    ....
    rowData.save(function (err) {
```

So your promises array isn't filled with all the promise.

To loop async use async module :

```
var async = require("async");
var models = []; // my models array

// async loop, with 10 in same time, e is the element, i the index in models
async.eachOfLimit(models, 10, function(e, i, cb){

   anAsyncFunction(function(err){
      return cb(err);
   });

}, function(err, result{

     // all done
});
```